# wrap bootstrap full slider in div make it not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use bootstrap full slider but after wrapping it into a div the slider not working and after removing parent div slider working fine, how to fix it?

```
<div><!--this div prevent slider show-->
    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        .............................
    </header>
</div>
```

I publish code on plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7tYjv4?p=preview
If uncomment div, slider not work how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set styling `height:100%` for the parent div.